# Use VLOOKUP to pass cell reference to a public variable?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a userform that opens on cell change in a column. 
That userform contains checkboxes, which all trigger a second userform with a text box which looks up a cell on a hidden sheet for its contents. (The checkbox that's ticked determines which cell the textbox looks for). The user then edits the box, clicks a button, and the new text is written back to the same cell.

This is the VBA for when the checkbox is ticked. It works great. Hooray!

```
Dim vln As Variant
Dim reta As Worksheet

Set reta = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RetailerActivity")
Set vln = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -3)

UserForm2.TextBox1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(vln, reta.Range("A1:Z100"), 3, False)

UserForm2.TescoSave.Visible = True
UserForm2.Show

End Sub
```

When the textbox has been edited, I would like to write it back to the same cell it came from. I figure the easiest way to do that is to have a public variable (as range), and to pass the result of the vlookup into that variable so the second userform can have a line which reads

```
Private Sub ASave_Click()

publicvariable.Value = TextBox1.Value
userform1.hide

End Sub
```

Nice and easy, rather than doing a VLookup again. Right?

Either way, I can't seem to set the public variable as the lookup.

Outside of any sub I have

```
Public bums As Range
```

And in the code above, after the bit where I've set the text box, I've tried to add the line

```
Set bums = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(vln, reta.Range("A1:Z100"), 3, False)
```

But the code errors with a "type mismatch".

If I try

```
Set bums = Range(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(vln, reta.Range("A1:Z100"), 3, False))
```

I get method "Range" of object "_global" failed.

I code by cobbling bits off the internet, as you can probably tell, so this is I don't doubt a complete kludge.

Any advice would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

VLookup returns a value, not a Range. You could use Match to find the row and then `Cells` to get the actual reference - for example:

```
Dim vMatch
vMatch = Application.Match(vln, reta.Range("A1:A100"),0)
If Not IsError(vMatch) then 
Set bums = reta.Cells(vMatch, "C")
else
msgbox "No match for " & vln
Exit Sub
End If
```

Personally I would also not use a public variable, but create a property for Userform2 to which you can assign the range.